# Laravel: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\bz2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error whenever I'm using the **php artsian command**:

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\bz2**

There is no **bz2** in **C:\xampp\php\ext**

I tried reinstalling Composer but that did not change anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If there's no bz2 extension then try removing the `extension=bz2.dll` from your php.ini

Comment: Clean up the question a bit